# Trying to use a Windows Batch script to delete files older that a certain date BUT want to exclude folders with a certain name

Tags: batch-file, directory

So what I want to do is use the batch script to delete off files on my data directory on my server(I have already created a archive copy just need to delete the files now). Problem is we use roaming profiles and if I ran this on the data directory it would go though and delete all kinds of ini's and application files that are needed but not changed very often.

```
forfiles -s -m *.* /D -01/01/2014 /C "cmd /c del @path"
```

If possible I would like to run a script like this but exclude any folder that has profile or profile.V2 in it and anything under it.

My directory structure looks something like this.

C:/Data/Users/srodgers/profile/Desktop

-or-

C:/Data/Users/ssmith/profile.V2/Desktop

and I would like to run the script from the root of data

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use PowerShell for this?

Comment: I don't know why people vote to close questions like this: which provide all the details needed to answer the question.  There is even code provided.

Comment: John, I dont have a problem using powershell but I don't know a good way to do it in power shell either. Regardless foxdrive figured it out. Thanks again foxdrive!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test this and remove the `echo` (it currently just displays the del commands) to acually delete the files.
In limited testing it's working fine.

```
@echo off
forfiles -s -m *.* /D -01/01/2014 /C "cmd /c echo @path |find /i /v 0x22\profile\0x22|find /i /v 0x22\profile.V2\0x22 >nul && echo del @path"
pause
```

Comment: Oh my god foxdrive you are a Genius! That will save me SO much time! In my limited testing it worked fine form me. Even when I use it though I will have a backup.